# Unit testing with Realm in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I followed the guide on Realm's website, but my test are still producing varying results, depending on the random order they are done.

Either they succeed when run individually, or fail because the data was already set. For example:

```
XCTAssert(observer.events[0].value.element == "", "Initail hub name is expected to be equal to be an empty string but was \(String(describing: observer.events[0].value.element))")
XCTAssert(observer.events[1].value.element == testHubName, "Initail hub name is expected to be equal to be the name we set but was \(String(describing: observer.events[1].value.element))")
```

In this example, `event[0]` is already set to `testHubName`.
Or it gets a `@throw RLMException(@"Object has been deleted or invalidated.");`
So I guess there is some kind race going around, but this is in my `setup` method:

```
func setupRealm() {
    testRealm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "DORSessionViewModelTestsRealm"))
    try! self.testRealm.write {
        self.testRealm.deleteAll()
    }
}
```

So as far as I understand I should have a fresh Realm for every test, so where is the race going on?

Edit: 
Adding a bigger part of the class

```
class DORSessionViewModelTests: XCTestCase {

var disposeBag: DisposeBag = DisposeBag()
var scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
var testRealm: Realm!


override func setUp() {

    super.setUp()
    setupRealm()
    setupRx()
}


override func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
}

func testHubNameLabelTextUpdate() {
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "expect hub name text to update")
    let testHubName = "testHubName"
    let viewModel = getSessionViewModel()

    let observer = scheduler.createObserver(String.self)
    scheduler.start()
    let hubNameDriver = viewModel.hubNameLabelText()
    hubNameDriver.asObservable().subscribe(observer).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    hubNameDriver.asObservable().skip(1).subscribeNext { _ in expectation.fulfill()}.disposed(by: disposeBag)

    try! self.testRealm.write {
        viewModel.dependencies..hub.name = testHubName
    }


    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5, handler: { error in
        XCTAssert(observer.events[0].value.element == "", "Initail hub name is expected to be equal to be an empty string but was \(String(describing: observer.events[0].value.element))")
        XCTAssert(observer.events[1].value.element == testHubName, "Initail hub name is expected to be equal to be the name we set but was \(String(describing: observer.events[1].value.element))")
    })
}

func setupRx() {
    disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
}
```

Comment: The exception you're seeing suggests that some part of your code continues to hold a reference to a Realm object after your call to `testRealm.deleteAll()` has deleted it. You likely also need to reset this state in between tests. It's hard to tell from the information you've provided what part of your code is holding this reference, or what the reference is to.

Comment: I'll try to debug this reference being kept. I also added more information. Maybe it will be easier to understand.